# How many connections does an ADO connection pool contain?

Tags: sql-server, connection, ado, max, pool

As part of evaluating the load on our SQL server, I'm trying to find out how many connections can I open before ADO will open another pool.

Other than testing it empirically - can anyone has a reference to an official number/white paper on the subject?

Thanks.

Comment: ADO, and the max number of connections per pool

Answer (score 0):

Every connection pool is associated with a distinct connection string and that too, it is specific to the application. In turn, what it means is – a separate connection pool is maintained for every distinct process, app domain and connection string.

see details here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ADONET_ConnectionPooling.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for ADO (and not ADO.NET) answer, and not for the amount of pools, but for the amount of connections per pool.